# Getting div to line up next to each other

Tags: css, html

How would I modify the css to get "Welcome" and "Already a member? Sign in" divs right next to each other rather than underneath each other?

Many thanks in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/methuselah/uXFt6/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `float` property for your `<div>`. So try it like this:

```
<div style="float: right;">Already a member? Sign in</div>
```

**Note:** Here is working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/uXFt6/9/).

**Note 2:** If you want to have sign in `<div>` on left, just set `float: left` property for your `<span>`

Answer (score 1):

float:left; will most likely be useful. See edited fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/uXFt6/7/

Answer (score 1):

or another way is add `float:left` css property on Welcome's Span

```
 <span style="font-size : x-large;float:left">Welcome</span>
```

see here : http://jsfiddle.net/uXFt6/14/

Answer (score 1):

This jsFiddle does the trick. See the comments for the changes made.

http://jsfiddle.net/uXFt6/15/